# IndexedDB methods with no arguments giving `TypeError` instead of `DataError`

Tags: indexeddb

For certain methods (at least `IDBIndex.get`, `IDBIndex.getKey`, and `IDBObjectStore.delete`), passing in no arguments gives a `TypeError` whereas the corresponding steps in the spec do not mention this (and would instead suggest a `DataError`-type `DOMException`). Is this a bug in the spec or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invalid or missing arguments are handled at the "Web IDL" level. See:

https://heycam.github.io/webidl/

The Web IDL spec defines what happens between your JavaScript code and the abstract types used in the spec, and how methods are called. It defines, for example, that `TypeError` should be thrown if insufficient arguments are passed, or how to convert an Array like`["s1", "s2"]` to the **sequence<DOMString>** type used in the spec.